# Turing complete Language that produces proofs for its results

Tags: solution-verification, computational-complexity, cryptography

Would it be possible to create a Turing complete programming language, where the result of a program always includes a easy to verify proof that the result is valid. Let me explain in more details.

Lets say that any program **P** of this programming language takes an input **x** and produces an output **(y, p)** where **y** is the *normal* output of the program and **p** is a proof that P(x) = y.
Obviously, validating this proof should not consist  in just rerunning the program but should be possible without doing so (ideally in linear time).

I would for now assume that all operations of the programming language are deterministic and no user inputs or similar things are allowed.

In addition, I would also allow as proof one that is just having a very high probability of being true.

If it is not possible to create such a language why?

Comment: There are decision problems of "arbitrarily high" time complexity (eg for any computable function $f$, there is a decision problem that takes $\Omega(f(x))$ time to solve). Let's say we could find a witness of length $O(f(x))$ and check the witness in $O(f(x))$ time. Then we could iterate through all possible witnesses and check them in $O(f(2^{O(f(x))}))$ time. So clearly, there is no way to put a uniform computable bound $f$ on the difficulty of providing a "proof".

Comment: [Model checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_checking) *is most often applied to hardware designs. For software, because of undecidability the approach cannot be fully algorithmic, apply to all systems, and always give an answer; in the general case, it may fail to prove or disprove a given property.* So your demand cannot be generally applied, of course by no means it cannot be achieved for certain types of programs, especially those with limited small number of states (for example Hoare logic can handle such simple cases)...

Comment: @mohottnad when i understand your argument correctly, then i'm not so sure that this is really a proof: It just says that there are some undecidable problems but that would also mean that in the first place there doesn't exist such a program, and would therefore be irrelevant to my question ... ?

Comment: I didn't claim I proved anything (especially as a comment), just mentioned some (potentially) useful reference to point to some background which seems to me your question is related to model checking (formal verification) is CS...